# how to break a string and insert it into list(array) in flutter dart

Tags: arrays, string, flutter, dart

am new to flutter and dart, I want to break a string and make some calculations from the middle value of the string which comes from scanning a QR code, somebody please help.

Comment: Please be more specific. Give an example of the kind of string you to operate on and the result that you want to get.

Comment: It will be fine if you add some code snippets and examples to make the question clear @taha

Comment: I Don't Have code written yet from that functionality.@RaguSwaminathan

Comment: basically am making a QRcode scanner app that scans a QR code and gets some value, now I want to make some calculations in the value, but the problem here is the value which I want to calculate is in the center of the sentence. so how do I take out the value which I want from that sentence? hope you understood. @Christian

Answer (score 2):

You can use String **Split**, it will split the string based on given split text

example

```
   var string = "hello world"; //this string need to splited
     List<String> list = string.split(" "); //by space" " the string need to splited
     print("list"); //list object holds ['hello','world']

     String firstString = list[0];
     String secondString = list[1];
     print(firstString); //hello
     print(secondString); //world
```

updated answer
User Regex to split a string by " " and get words in list

```
String QRstring = "kjrufqvbaSLIVBQERI 34685 aeonkfvbjrgq 349585";
List<String> list = QRstring.split(new RegExp(r" ")); // this will split by space
print(list);
print(list[0]); //kjrufqvbaSLIVBQERI
print(list[1]); //34685
print(list[2]); //aeonkfvbjrgq
print(list[3]); //349585
```

Comment: how do I then take values from it and use it?

Comment: you can get split text by asigning to List, please refer updated answer

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: thank you so much it works but how can I remove 'el' or more than 1 alphabet or from the hello and print the rest string 'hello world'.

Comment: { kjrufqvbaSLIVBQERI   34685   aeonkfvbjrgq   349585 }  this is the string which am getting from scanning the qr code now i want to add the 2 set of  numbers you see above how can i do it.

Comment: I want to remover the 2 sets of numbers from there and add them

Comment: Navin brother please help

Comment: You can split this string by using space " ".. list = stringQR.split(" ");.  list[0] and list[2] conatins characters and list[1] list[3] contains number..

Comment: it gives comma to every letter rather than words

Comment: I mean it separates the lists in letters rather than words

Comment: i got a solution for this

Comment: this is what I get after splitting -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- [main_item tag_no item_name purity pcs gwt st_less nwt perc vad_per vad_am grate mc rc st_pcs strate stamt tamt ratetyp PlusDate
CHAIN CNM353 ITALIAN, CHAIN 750 1 {4.06} 0 4.06 0 15 {0.609} 2921 200 0 0 0 0 2921 Gold, Rate 29/03/2018]----------------------------------------------------------------------, above is the real string which i get from scaning. and the number which i want to add is which i have wrapped in curly braces. looking forward for your help brother.

Comment: the number is in the double type and can be more than 5 digits sometimes